# Slow rendering after switching from Geopackage to SQL Server Spatial

Tags: qgis, sql-server, rendering, speed

I have a table of 13500 points, all in OSGB 27700, which was in a GeoPackage.  My QGIS 3.28.1 project displayed and stylised these very quickly when panning and zooming (almost instant).  I have to move this data to SQL Server 2022 in order to use the data as part of a Report Server.  Both QGIS and SQL Server are on the same development computer, which is fairly highly specified for CPU, memory and disc.

Having migrated the data, set up the geometry_columns, added spatial and non-spatial indexes, etc the data displays in QGIS but renders very slowly (perhaps 10x the time compared with GeoPackage).

I thought the problem was the query, but capturing it in SQL Profiler and running it natively in Management Studio, it is very fast (10ms after a pan, returning 22 points in the view).  It seems the data gets to QGIS fast enough, but then QGIS is doing a lot of processing before it is drawn (maybe 6s to redraw each time, which feels like an age when panning across a large area). I have checked that parallel rendering is enabled.  My guess is that QGIS is taking a long time to convert the geometry from SQL, but it shouldn't be doing any re-projection; I think everything is set up for 27700.  The styling is pretty simple, and reducing it to generic circles doesn't speed things up.

Can anyone suggest other things I should try? Or is SQL Server always going to be very slow in comparison with GeoPackage and I should just live with it?

Comment: *Points* should not take any time at all to "convert" (complex polygon geometries, however, are a different story).

Comment: I agree.  But there is a delay somewhere in the pipeline that I'm trying to understand.  Query seems fast and reports as such when run in SQL Management Studio.  The next stages are transmission from SQL Server to QGIS - on the same box this should be fast but I can't think of how to measure it.  Conversion of SQL data to QGIS internal format (should be fast as we are dealing with points, and all in the same projection as the target QGIS view).  Rendering the data (should be fast).  I'm stumped!

Comment: Further to this, I set up the same project in ArcGIS Pro and have very responsive rendering, so I do not think the problem is on the SQL Server end.  I have also installed a clean SQL 2022 and QGIS 3.32 on a different computer and still see very slow rendering in QGIS with the same data.

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds like a dev team issue for QGIS then.